# using a base 3 decimal to express as a base 10 fraction using geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

> Express $0.\overline{21}_3$ as a base 10 fraction in reduced form.

So I was able to solve it by setting $x=\overline{.21}$, but the solution also briefly mentioned another way using the geometric series:

> A quick way to get the answer by using the geometric series is: $(0.212121 \ldots)_3 = \frac{7}{9} + \frac{7}{81} + \frac{7}{729} + \dots = \frac{7}{8}.$

However, I'm having a hard time understanding how to actually use the geometric series (the above answer is not clear to me).

Comment: Are you having problem understanding why (0.21212121...) = 7/9... or why 7/9... = 7/8 ?

Comment: $.21_3= \left(\frac 23\right)_{10}+ \left(\frac 19\right)_{10}= \left(\frac 79\right)_{10}$

Comment: @ leyanpan I meant the first part, since the geometric sum can  be found by setting r=1/9 and a=7/9

Comment: Nit picking here. "Decimal" means a base ten number. It would have been better to say "base three number".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
   (0.212121 \ldots)_3
   &= \dfrac{21_3}{100_3} 
    + \dfrac{21_3}{(100_3)^2} 
    + \dfrac{21_3}{(100_3)^3} + \cdots\\
   &= \frac 79 + \frac{7}{9^2} + \frac{7}{9^3} + \cdots \\
   &= \frac 79\left( \dfrac{1}{1-\frac 19} \right) \\  
   &= \frac 79 \cdot \frac 98 \\
   &= \frac 78.
\end{align}

You could also use the old shift and subtract trick...

\begin{array}{rcl}
   100_3x &= &21.212121 \ldots_3 \\
   x &= &\phantom{0}0.212121 \ldots_3 \\
\hline
   22_3x &= &21_3 \\
   8x &= &7 \\
   x &= \dfrac 78
\end{array}

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure on how to compute $(0.2121\ldots)_{3}$, we have: $$\begin{align} E = (0.\color{red}{2}\color{green}{1}\color{red}{2}\color{green}{1}\ldots)_3 = \frac{1}{3}\times \color{red}{2} + \frac{1}{3^2}\times \color{green}{1} + \frac{1}{3^3}\times \color{red}{2} + \frac{1}{3^4}\times \color{green}{1} + \ldots \\ = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{2}{27} + \frac{1}{81} + \ldots \\ = \frac{7}{9}+ \frac{7}{81}+\ldots \end{align}$$

---

Now note that: $$\begin{align} E = \frac{7}{9}+\frac{7}{81}+\frac{7}{729}+\ldots \\ =\frac{7}{9}+\frac{7}{9}\times \frac{1}{9} + \frac{7}{9}\times [\frac{1}{9}]^2\ldots \\ =\frac79(1+\frac19 + [\frac19]^2+\ldots)\end{align}$$

Now, this is an [infinite geometric progression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series). Can you compute the required sum?

Answer (score 1):

In base $3$ the digits $21$ represent the number $2 \times 3 + 1 = 7$.

In base $3$ moving the "decimal point" right two spaces is dividing by $3 \times 3 = 9$. Adding up your infinite decimal two places at a time tells you the sum is
$$
\frac{7}{9}\left( 1 + \frac{1}{9}   + \frac{1}{81} + \cdots \right) = 
\frac{7}{9} \times \frac{1}{1 - 1/9} .
$$

Comment: I don't understand why I should use 7 (which is a base 10, not base 3 number) when moving the decimal point is done in base 3...

Comment: The $7$ is the base $10$ number written in base $3$ as $21_3$. That has nothing to do with moving the decimal point. When you do convert $21_3$ to $0.21_3$ you have multiplied by $1/9$ (base $10$).

Answer (score 0):

You have

$(0.212121 \ldots)_3 = \frac{7}{9} + \frac{7}{81} + \frac{7}{729} + \dots$

and for $0<a<1$

$1+a+a^2+\ldots = \dfrac{1}{1-a}$

from which

$\begin {align}
(0.212121 \ldots)_3 &= 7\left(\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{81} + \frac{1}{729} + \dots 
 \right)\\
 &= 7\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{9}} -1 \right)\\
 &= 7\left(\frac{9}{8} -1 \right)\\
 &= \frac{7}{8} \\
\end{align}$

---

You can also (perhaps this is what you actually did) multiply by $100_3 = 9_{\text{dec}}$ to see that for $x=0.\overline{21}_3$, $9x-x = 21_3 = 7_{\text{dec}}$ and solve from there.